# How do I show the following pdf is a density function

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

How do I show the following pdf is a density function? Suppose that

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4} &\mbox{ if } \;|x|<1, \\ 
\frac{1}{4x^2} &\mbox{ if } \;|x|\ge 1. \\ 
\end{cases}
$$

So I have

$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4x^2} \,dx= \infty,
$$

this is obviously wrong can someone tell me where I did wrong, thanks.

Comment: You should integrate $1/4$ only for $-1 < x < 1$, and $1/(4 x^2)$ for $-\infty < x < 1$ and $1 < x < \infty)$.

Comment: what is $fx(x)$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael for 1/(4x^2) I think we should integrate for $-\infty < x < -1 $ and then 1 < x < $\infty $ correct ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, that's what I meant.  Somehow a $-$ got lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\int_{-1}^{1}{\frac {1}{4}}\,dx $+$\int_{1}^{\infty}{\frac {1}{4x^2}}\,dx $+$\int_{-\infty}^{-1}{\frac {1}{4x^2}}\,dx$=$\frac {1}{2} $+$\frac {1}{4} $+$\frac {1}{4} $=1.
So the given function is a pdf.

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct answer.